# C++ templates: separation of definition and implementation using template arguments

Tags: c++, templates, visual-c++, c++11

To be honest, I do not really know how to name that problem. I'll just show the code that is not working:

```
template<int SIZE>
struct bar{

};

template<int SIZE>
struct foo{
    template<int X>
    void f(bar<X> b);
};

template<int SIZE, int X>
void foo<SIZE>::f(bar<X> b){

}


int main(){
    foo<1> f;
    bar<2> b;
}
```

I'd like to separate definition from implementation to avoid cyclic dependency issues. Separation is done in header files only, I don't want to put template code into cpp files. Using pointers is no option in that case. Refactoring has been considered but is not a real option, either.

Implementing foo::f without a parameter that has template parameters itself is working fine. I do not really get the problem with that parameter, though.

Code should work using gcc 4.7 and (even more important) Visual Studio 2010. C++11 is ok as long as supported by the platforms mentioned.

Solutions, workarounds as well as theoretical explanations why I'm doing something completly wrong will be highly appreciated. TIA.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
template<int SIZE, int X>    //problem : what is what here?
void foo<SIZE>::f(bar<X> b){

}
```

It is wrong syntax.

The correct syntax is to use `template` twice as:

```
template<int SIZE>   //for the class template
template<int X>      //for the member function template
void foo<SIZE>::f(bar<X> b){

}
```

Note that the order matters here.

Answer (score 5):

This is the right syntax:

```
template<int SIZE>
template<int X>
void foo<SIZE>::f(bar<X> b){

}
```

You are otherwise saying that `foo` is a class template that takes 2 template arguments.

Answer (score 4):

There are two levels of templates, and you have to specify them separately

```
template<int SIZE>
template<int X>
void foo<SIZE>::f(bar<X> b){  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Cyclic dependencies are your main problem. Do you really need them? Try to break your problem in a way where dependencies form a Directed Acyclic Graph and more often than not, you will end up with a better solution.

If you cannot break the cyclic dependencies, then maybe you should reconsider whether the two templates should be in different components (in this case headers), as none of the two seems to be valid without the other.

Comment: @Nawaz: I am assuming there is once, due to the line: *I'd like to separate definition from implementation to avoid cyclic dependency issues* Then again, as House says *people lie*, so you cannot always trust what the question says

Comment: I think because of the compilation error, he incorrectly concluded that it is because of the cyclic dependency issues (which don't even exists).